# How to abandon a whole topic on Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

So the long and short of the issue is that, in a fit of fanatical adherence to code review principles and user attribution....

I pushed around 834 commits from an upstream branch to a project's gerrit server.

I was since then informed me that I ought to have (reasonably) first pushed a squashed commit for testing on gerrit and then pointed them to my repo for a merge...

Luckily I had tagged the commits with a topic while uploading them (for ease of testing.... -_-)

How can I now mass abandon the whole damn topic there? (to be replaced with a squashed commit)

There ought to maybe be some sort of terminal command? My gerrit-fu is weak and I haven't any privileged access to the server though..

Comment: That's a lotta commits! Related for a patchset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856648/how-to-abandon-all-changes-of-an-entire-patchset-at-once-in-gerrit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no ready method to achieve this. However, `gerrit` is awesome tool and you can solve this problem by writing a custom script.

Sorry, I'm too lazy to make you a ready to use solution, but here's what my script would do:

1. Prepare environment

   ```bash
   alias gerrit="ssh -p 29418 gerrit.yourdomain.com gerrit"
   ```
2. List all the commits with topic:

   ```
   gerrit query topic:<topic>
   ```
3. Strip `Change-Id`'s
4. Abandon commits one by one:

   ```
   gerrit review <id> --abandon
   ```

**Update**

Thanks to Marcelo Avila de Oliveira, you have now the script you can use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

alias gerrit="ssh -p 29418 gerrit.yourdomain.com gerrit"

for c in $(gerrit query topic:trololo | grep "сhange" | cut -d ' ' -f 2);
    do gerrit review $c --abandon;
done
```

Replace `trololo` with whatever you need, or adapt the script to take the argument.

Comment: In step 2, you need to use "gerrit query topic:<topic>". To improve, replace the steps 2-3 to: for c in $(gerrit query topic:<topic> | grep change | cut -d ' ' -f 2); do gerrit review $c --abandon; done

Comment: You're welcome. I think you need to change "Change-Id" to "change" in the grep. Please check.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira I did some tests. You're right.

Comment: in gerrit v2.13, gerrit review need to specify which patchset you want to review. therefore the review command param has been changed into {changeid,patchset} or {commithash}. Therefore $c should either be changed into $commithash or {$changid, $patchset}. I prefer the previous one: for c in $(gerrit query --current-patch-set topic:trololo | grep "revision" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3);

Answer (score 1):

Comment --> answer so the code is readable.  Because lack of code in answer meant I didn't understand lanyusea solved 1/2 of my problems with original answer.  Unfortunately I couldn't tell because of the lack of formatting :(  ... but I am adding something new ... i swear

A few problems I found (we just updated gerrit ... so it could just be a temporary bug)

- Neither Commit-Id nor change number were valid
- Spaces in --message didn't work

So change:

- Added query --current-patch-set
- grep for "revision"
- cut on ':' instead of space (not sure it was needed ... i just felt better with leading whitespace)
- Escape all of the spaces in the message (I need to remember to file a bug for this one)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

alias gerrit="ssh -p 29418 gerrit.yourdomain.com gerrit"

for id in $(gerrit query topic:yolo --current-patch-set | grep "revision" | cut -d ':' -f 2); do
    gerrit review --abandon $id -m "Abandoning\ for\ reasons"
done
```

All credit to Andrejs and every single person on that thread

And turned into a re-usable function you can source.  It handles the escaping, gives feedback about what its doing, and runs without usual query limits:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

alias gerrit="ssh -p 29418 gerrit.yourdomain.com gerrit"

gerrit_abandon_patches() {(
    set -e

    local message="$1"
    shift 1 # remove message

    local id=
    local commit=

    #Quote spaces in message to work around gerrit bug
    message=${message//[ ]/\\ }
    

    IFS=$'\n' # We don't need to scope because we are in a closure
    
    for commit in $(gerrit query "$@" --current-patch-set --no-limit --format JSON | grep -e '"id":' ); do
        commit=$( echo "$commit" | sed -e 's/["{}]//g' -e 's/,/\n/g' )
        id=$(echo "$commit" | grep -e 'revision' | cut -d ':' -f 2 )

        echo "Abandoning: $id"
        echo "$commit" | grep \
            -e url \
            -e id \
            -e revision \
            -e commitMessage
        echo

        gerrit review --abandon $id -m "$message"
    done

)}
```

Comment: This is now the correct answer with newer versions of Gerrit.